# Are finalizers triggered when an application crashes?

Tags: c#, exception, crash, finalizer

When an application crashes, either when run normally or when run in the Visual Studio debugger, are finalizers triggered?

Comment: An application crash can be many things. Exit of the framework, unhandled exception, etc... so it depends.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514688/destructor-does-it-get-called-if-the-app-crashes, plus see the answer by Hans Passant